# Pressing Enter in textarea using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ember.js

In an acceptance test, pressing Enter key after text input triggers an event. I tried to fillIn text and hit enter with the keyEvent.

PS: Testem ignores the keyEvent.

HTML:

```
<div class="issue-container">
<div class="create-container">
<div class="input-field ui-textarea md-animated ember-view">
<label id="ember1369-label" for="ember1369-input" class="active">Add an issue</label>
<textarea data-test-id="txtid" id="ember1369-input" class="md-textarea" style="height: 21.5px; overflow: hidden;"></textarea></div></div></div>
```

Acceptance test:

```
test('review-an-element', async function(assert) {
await fillIn(testSelector('txtid'), 'Input is typed here and then hit enter');
await keyEvent(testSelector('txtid'), 'keypress', 13);}); //hitting enter
```

My jQuery attempt:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keyup");
e.which = 13;
e.keyCode = 13;    
await $('.md-textarea').trigger(e);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution with jQuery.

```
var e = $.Event('keydown', { keyCode: 13 });

test('txtarea', async function(assert){
await fillIn($('.md-textarea')[0], 'text is entered here');
await $('.md-textarea').trigger(e);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the `keyup` event, not the `keypress` event.  The `keypress` event fires only for keys that produce output, like letter keys. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress

**For your acceptance test:**

*change*

```js
await keyEvent(testSelector('txtid'), 'keypress', 13);
```

*to*

```
await keyEvent(testSelector('txtid'), 'keyup', 13);
```

Edit: The `testSelector()` helper is deprecated - https://github.com/simplabs/ember-test-selectors/pull/134

Comment: Super like for the info on deprecation. Can you tell me how to do it in jQuery.